# sha-256 hashing in python

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I wanted to create a python program thats asks for an input then hashes(sha-256) the input then prints it. Does this already exist? How would I go about doing so.

Comment: Check out [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

using `hashlib`:

```
from hashlib import sha256

input_ = input('Enter something: ')
print(sha256(input_.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Note: This throws a NameError in Python 2.7. So, if you get that error, you need to change your interpreter to Python 3.